# React Native application get slow after enabling Hermes Engine

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

Need Help.
I make a new react-native project by https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup Creating a new application.

I found the application getting slow after enabling the Hermes Engine.

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.69.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

What's wrong with it.
I created this project by using official demo step by step.

Expect:
The application become more faster after enabling Hermes Engine, or at least same as before.

After enabling Hermes:
https://cdn.kapwing.com/final_63706fb6f238a300250643ab_920899.gif

Before enabling Hermes:
https://cdn.kapwing.com/final_63706eadda957601151f3c33_364532.gif

Comment: The images are not accessible. Please avoid adding links to posts for this reason. Are you running release builds in both cases?